# trying to resize root partition using lvm doesn't work

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, lvm, parted

I'm working on an ubuntu 18.04 server. For the last few days I keep getting the error message "No space left on device" when doing simple things like `ll`.

I have found out that it has something to do with the fact that my root partition somehow got full.

```
$df -h 
Filesystem                                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv                     130G  130G     0 100% /
...
/dev/sda2                                             976M  211M  699M  24% /boot
/dev/sda1                                             511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--0                           12T  787G   11T   7% /home
...
```

When creating the server I have used a raid6 structure to create one physical volume (16 hard drives), one volume group and two logical volumes. I have used LVM to partition the VG into two logical volumes, one for `root` with ~132G and a second one for the `home` directory with ~12T (the rest)

```
$ sudo lvdisplay -m
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  LV Name                ubuntu-lv
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                d6ihzF-rV8o-RSJA-9cDw-7O5t-x1uC-6PVUHg
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2019-02-25 11:33:31 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                132.00 GiB
  Current LE             33792
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extents 0 to 1023:
    Type        linear
    Physical volume /dev/sda3
    Physical extents    0 to 1023

  Logical extents 1024 to 33791:
    Type        linear
    Physical volume /dev/sda3
    Physical extents    3183807 to 3216574


  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/lv-0
  LV Name                lv-0
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                xJ0jjx-Bmnv-itG6-HR8k-eySF-HCXf-GRi6Rb
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2019-02-25 11:33:32 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                12.14 TiB
  Current LE             3182783
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extents 0 to 3182782:
    Type        linear
    Physical volume /dev/sda3
    Physical extents    1024 to 3183806
```

I would like now to increase my `root` partition, but I keep getting into the same problem.

I have tried using `lvextend` and `lvresize` but this didn't help.

```
lvextend -L+128G /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv 
  Insufficient free space: 32768 extents needed, but only 0 available
```

and the same also for `lvresize`.

I was wondering what I need to do to be able to increase the size of the root partition.

Does the fact that the `/home/` partition takes the rest of the "free space" has anything to do with it? Do I need to decrease its size first before I can increase the `root` partition? 
How can I do that?

Comment: You need free space to extend a logical volume.

Comment: Yes I would say so, you need to reduce the home to let root take up space...

Comment: Can I reduce the home directory also with `lvm resize -L -100G ...`? Would this command delete any data if there is still enough space on this logical volume?

Comment: Do not attempt to shrink your `/home` LVM VG without a better understanding of Linux filesystems. **You must have adequate backups of your computer/data because if you screw up, you will lose everything.** You cannot resize `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--0` without first shrinking the filesystem that lives on it. Also, you typically cannot increase or resize the partitions of your filesystem if they are mounted. This can make resizing a root partition difficult because you must boot from a USB stick or something similar to work on it.

Comment: I would highly recommend that instead of trying to resize your partitions, you figure out why your root partition (`/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`) is full, and try to reduce its disk usage. On most computers I manage, the root partition can fit into a 15 GB space. Try: `apt-get clean`, which will delete old packages cached on your computer. That may give you some breathing room. Next, install something like [`filelight`](https://utils.kde.org/projects/filelight/) to see what's is taking up all the disk space.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of LVM works like an onion:

1. The physical volume does not have free space presumably, so you cannot extend it for that reason. Use 'pvs' to have an overview here, it will probably show up with 0 byte of free space. It is basically a partition on hard drive
2. Inside you have one or more Volume groups. That is the first abstraction layer ( use command *vgs* or *vgscreate*, *vgsextend*)
3. Inside you have the logical volumes
4. Inside the logical volumes resides the file system, for example ext2, ext3, btrfs or ext4.

Important to note, the sub sets of command over the different layers of the lvm have the same naming policy. So *extend*, *reduce*, *resize*, *create* and so on, you will find the related prefixes for every abstraction layer, and the use is standardized with same args, for example *pvcreate*, *vgvcreate*, *lvcreate* and so on. Once you have understood the syntax and the architecture it is easy to work with it.

So you need space to extend in the pvs, than after extending, you need to assign it to your logical volume group (/dev/"volumegroupname") and after it you need to assign some or all of this space to your logical volume with *lvextend* or *lvresize* (will be mapped like /dev/mapper/"vgname-lvname" in Ubuntu). In the end you need to resize the filesystem inside the logical volume (lv, command *lvs*). Make also an *ext2fsck -f* on the file system afterwards.

If you want to shrink, you must use resize2fs, than use lvreduce or lvresize, and finally and eventually shrink the physical volume. So vice versa. It is absolutely necessary to understand the basic concept here.
LVMs were made for easy administration and extending or adding hard drive disk space to an existing system. So you can even extend to a second hard drive for example, and extend the logical volume over these two hard drives. But that use case I haven't had so far for my private systems. You could also use raid0 and raid1 for more safety of your data. And i.E. luks for your security. So it is a really nice idea!

Example case:

1. You buy a new ssd with double space
2. You start Ubuntu live, and install clonezilla in it
3. You clone the old partition 1:1 to the new device
4. You follow these instructions on [unix.stackechange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322631/279105) :D , but you skip the steps with luks, as you have no encrypted hard disk (like I can only recommend it)

Good luck! Be aware, that you can mess up parts or even the complete system if you do not obey the above "philosophy". I please encourage anyone to improve this explanation, cause I only got this by my own bloody experiences. I hoped at least, this could ease the pain for anyboding reading this having no idea, what is going on.